# How do I only show the most recent item in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show the most recent item in an array on the webpage but I am confused to as to how I should be doing this. I can't change anything the query since i still do need the other items in the array for something else.

## my queries

```
$arrWezen = array();

    $query_wezen = 
    "SELECT 
        MythischeWezens.ID as idWezen,
        MythischeWezens.naam as wezenNaam,
        Afkomst.ID as idAfkomst,
        Afkomst.Afkomst as Afkomst
    FROM MythischeWezens 
        JOIN Afkomst 
            ON MythischeWezens.idAfkomst = Afkomst.ID";

    $query_verhalen = 
    "SELECT 
        MythischeWezens.ID as idWezen,
        MythischeWezens.naam as wezenNaam,
        Verhaal.ID as idVerhaal,
        Verhaal.Titel as Titel,
        Verhaal.Verhaal as Verhaal
    
    FROM LinkWezenVerhaal
        JOIN MythischeWezens 
            ON LinkWezenVerhaal.idWezen = MythischeWezens.ID
        JOIN Verhaal
            ON LinkWezenVerhaal.idVerhaal = Verhaal.ID";

    $query_traits = 
        "SELECT 
            MythischeWezens.ID as idWezen,
            MythischeWezens.naam as wezenNaam,
            Traits.ID as idTrait,
            Traits.trait as Traits
        FROM LinkWezenTraits
            JOIN MythischeWezens 
                ON LinkWezenTraits.idWezen = MythischeWezens.ID
            JOIN Traits
                ON LinkWezenTraits.idTrait = Traits.ID";
    
    $result_wezen = $conn->query($query_wezen) or die($conn -> error);
    $result_verhalen  = $conn->query($query_verhalen) or die($conn -> error);
    $result_traits = $conn->query($query_traits) or die($conn -> error);

    if($result_wezen->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result_wezen->fetch_assoc()){
            $arrWezen[$row['idWezen']] = array('wezenNaam' => $row['wezenNaam'],'Afkomst' => $row['Afkomst']);

        }
    }

    if($result_verhalen ->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result_verhalen ->fetch_assoc()){
            $arrWezen[$row['idWezen']]['verhaal'][$row['idVerhaal']] = ['Titel' => $row['Titel'], 'Verhaal' => $row['Verhaal']];
        }
    }

    if ($result_traits->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result_traits->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arrWezen[$row['idWezen']]['traits'][$row['idTrait']] = $row['Traits'];
        }
    }
    
?>
```

## my functions

```
<?php 
include("getWezens.php");

function Wezen($arrWezen){
    $returnstring = "";
    foreach($arrWezen as $key => $val){
        if($val['idWezen'] ==$key){
            $returnstring .= 
                "<div class=\"col-md-4\">
                <div class=\"card\">
                    <div class=\"card-body\">
                        <h5 class=\"card-title\">{$val['wezenNaam']}</h5>
                        <p class=\"card-text\">afkomst: {$val['Afkomst']}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";     
        }
    } 
    return $returnstring;
}
?>
```

## My index page

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Mythical creatures</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Brand</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container my-4">
        <h1>Dorjee Website</h1>
        <p>See a bunch of mythical creatures!</p>
        <h2>Mythical Creatures</h2>
        <?php print Wezen($arrWezen) ?>
    </div>

    <footer class="bg-dark text-light text-center py-3">
        <p>&copy; 2023 Your Website. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried using `end()` in the if function but it doesn't count $key as an array nor `$val['idWezen']` it just tells me that it's expecting an array in it's parameters.

Comment: You have no `ORDER BY` in your queries, so they won't be ordered by date. Which column that you're selecting contains the date?

Comment: I have id's and i'm guessing i'm looking for the highest id number which is the most recent but none of the queries contains a date.

Comment: If you can't change the queries to use `ORDER BY`, you can put all the results in a PHP array, and then use `usort()` to sort them by the id column.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i did that or am i wrong? whenever i var_dump $arrWezens they show up in order of when i put them in

Comment: If the ID is reliable for showing the order you want, use `ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` in the SQL to just get the most recent

Comment: how do I show the other items in the array later on then?

Comment: Just remove the LIMIT bit. Then you'll still get all the results, but the newest will be the first one returned by the database.  These are fairly standard sql commands, it would help you if you familiarise yourself with them

Comment: okay i understand that but won't that just then show all of them again? i'll try it out and see what happens

Comment: I put the order by into my sql and i get this msg saying "Column 'ID' in order clause is ambiguous"

Comment: You must have more than one ID column in the results. So just prefix it with the table name it should come from, e.g. `YourTableName.ID`

Comment: `won't that just then show all of them`...not if you write code to just output the first one. When/where do you want to use the rest of the results? You could put them into an array and then output them elsewhere in your page

Comment: I found the fix for it thanks for your time kind person

Comment: No problem. I suggest adding your solution below in the Answers area, in case it's helpful for other people in future (who may then upvote it). See also [answer]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the original array by the ID with

```
usort()
```

Like this:

```
function Wezen($arrWezen){
    usort($arrWezen, function($a, $b) {
            return $a->ID - $b->ID;
        });
    return $arrWezen;
}
```